How to update iPhone phone number after port?
After changing mobile phone providers recently, I had my old number ported to my new account.  After porting was complete, my provider sent me a text message saying "If you have an iPhone, you'll need to update your number in your phone's device settings", and lo and behold in Settings > Phone > My Number the now-invalid temporary number is still shown.
I can edit the number but when I press save it goes back to being the temporary number.
How do I update the number to my actual phone number?  At the moment Messages and FaceTime only offer to let me receive messages on the temp number, not my (old, correct, ported) number.
I have tried toggling airplane mode, disabling iMessages and FaceTime, removing and reinserting the SIM, and restarting the phone to get it to update the number or allow me to—all to no avail.
(iPhone 13 mini, iOS 17.5.1.)

See if https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/399239/85275 or https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/464712/85275 helps

These appear to be asking something different than I am.  I am asking about a phone that does not know its own number.  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/377790/messages-and-facetime-stuck-with-temporary-number?rq=1 seems to be a closer match for my issue, but the answer there is vague and did not work for me.

The solution (courtesy Apple tech support chat; I suspect step 1 is optional but it's sensible that they check that I actually know my own number):

Verify that I control the number by adding it to my Apple ID security info:

Go to Settings > my name > Sign-in & Security.
Next to EMAIL & PHONE NUMBERS, press "Edit".
Press "Add email or phone number".
Choose "Add a Phone Number".
Follow prompts to add number and verify it by SMS or call.


Reset network settings:

Go to Settings > General > Transfer or Reset iPhone > Reset > Reset Network Settings.
Enter passcode.
Wait for phone to restart.



Once restarted, my new number showed up in Settings > Phone > My Number without further action on my part.

Superb. I had been trying all-sorts, but this fixed the same issue for me. The key part was resetting network settings.
Now I expect I have to log in to ALL my wifi networks again! oh well :)
